Pulling multiple sheet data from google sheet and displaying a table per sheet in GAS Web Application
I am new to using Google Apps Script. I was wondering if it is possible to take multiple sheets from Google sheets to be displayed in corresponding html datatables.
For example:
Sheet1 --> Table 1
Sheet2 --> Table 2
I know it is possible to do with a single sheet (example below), but how can I add a new table for sheet2 (or atleast be able to switch the table content from sheet1 or sheet2, vice versa)? I can think of using <a href="insertSheet2's table link"> here, but I'm looking for a more elegant way of doing it.
//Code.gs:
function doGet() { 
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate().setTitle("Sample Apps Script Web App"); 
}

// Get sheet data and add to array
function getData() { 
var spreadSheetId = "xxxxxxxxxx"; // Google sheets ID 
var dataRange = "Sheet1!A:Z"; // Range

// Fetch all retrieved sheet data from a specified range 
var range = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadSheetId, dataRange); 
var values = range.values;

//Columns I wish to show 
var selectedColumns = [0,1,2,3]; //Index             =  A,B,C,D

// Remove the first row selectedValues = selectedValues.slice(1);

return selectedValues; 
}

<!--Index.html-->
<div class="container">
            <table id="data-table" class="table table-striped table-sm table-hover table-bordered">
              <!-- TABLE DATA IS ADDED BY THE showData() JAVASCRIPT FUNCTION -->
            </table>
</div>

//JS:
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  // Initialize DataTable
  table = $('#data-table').DataTable({
    
    //"dom": "<'datatable-controls'<'dataTables_length'l><'dataTables_filter'f>>t<ip>",
    "sDom": "rtip", 
    columns: [{"title": "ColA"}, {"title": "ColB"}, {"title": "ColC"},{"title": "ColD"}]
}


Provide [mcve].
